# add id to kendo comboBox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I am using ASP.NET C# APP with razor code. I have kendo ComboBox that is printing drop down. Now what I want, get ID of selected value from drop-down (kendo UI ComboBox) and assign to input as class, ID. Note I have multiple instance of drop-down of comboBox.

### Razor input

```
 <td class="N_td">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model._MarkScheme.MarkSchemeId, null, new { @class = "ElementMarkingSchemeTitle k1-grid-input k-textbox_3 _MarkSchemeId_Input" })  
 </td>
```

### Kendo ComboBox in JQuery .. document.ready function

```
$("._MarkSchemeId_Input").kendoComboBox({
        minLength: 1,
        filter: 'contains',
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "ID",
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            serverFiltering: false,
            transport: {
                read: "/Qualification/GetAllMarkScheme_JSON"
            },
        },
        change: function () {

            //$(this).find("input.ElementMarkingSchemeTitle").addClass("xxxxxxxx");

            alert("value " + this.value() + "   " + this.text());                       
        }
 });
```

Comment: WHat do you mean by assign to input class? Do you want to change the css class of the input?

Comment: i want to pass the model._MarkScheme.MarkSchemeId which is the id of record

Comment: You can pass on the `$("#MarkSchemeId").val()` to your URL something like `read: "/Qualification/GetAllMarkScheme_JSON?SchemeId=" + $("#MarkSchemeId").val()`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the change event handler, you can get reference to the visible input with

```
 var $visibleInput = this.input;
```

Or you can get reference to the hidden input that is actually submitted like so:

```
 var hiddenInput = this.element;
```